# What are the requirements for a member to be elligible to participate in a Clan War?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What are the requirements to war in clash of clans?

We have 12 members but every time we war, one of our members can't participate.

We are the only clan this member has been in so why is he ineligible for wars?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate in title, but not in content.